# JavaScript - Object failing

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

This is the main problem:

```
var obj = {
  "22": false,
  "32": true,
}

console.log(obj.32) //<---- NOT WORKING??!?!?!
```

Why can't I reach the part of the object??

I know you can't begin variables with numbers but you can with object parts, so how can I read this?

Comment: Don't use a `,` at the end of an object definition. Old versions of IE break. It is allowed in ECMAScript5, but it's easier to just not include it

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
console.log(obj["32"]);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WrzbV/1/

Or `obj[32]` - the `32` will be converted to a string and will be found just the same as using `"32"`.

There are 2 ways to access an object by property name - bracket notation (what I suggested) and dot notation (what you're using). With dot notation, you must use a valid identifier, which `32` is not...just like you can't do `var 32 = "whatever";`

Reference:

- [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to access properties with numbers

either change the key to string

```
 var obj = {
    "i": false,
    "j": true,
}

 console.log(obj.i);
 console.log(obj.j);
```

or use

```
console.log(obj["32"])
```

Or if you can use jQuery  then use

```
  $.each(obj, function(key,value){

    console.log(key +' --  '+ value);

  });
```

Answer (score -1):

A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (`_`), or dollar sign (`$`).
in JavaScript, identifiers can't begin with a numeral.

As already said, use array syntax to access the object property as `obj["32"]`